# How to package multiple single modules as sub-package with python setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

My Directory structure looks like follows.

```
pkg-folder
├── LICENSE
├── pkg-name
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── module1
│   │   ├── module1.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── resourceFile.json
│   └── module2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── module2.py
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── MANIFEST.ini
└── setup.cfg
```

After building and installing the package I have to import as follows.

```
from pkg-name.module1.module1 import func1
```

How can I import directly like follows when i know module1.py will be a single file in the sub-package ?

```
from pkg-name.module1 import func1
```

My `__init__.py's` are blank.

Comment: You can probably rename `module1/module1.py` to `module1/__init__.py` and you are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've partially answered your own question:

> My `__init__.py`'s are blank.

When importing a package, the interpreter checks for name bindings in the package's `__init__.py` file. An *empty* `__init__.py` file only provides name bindings for submodules within the same directory. For example, if you have a package structure like

```
pkg_folder
└── pkg_name
    └── __init__.py
```

and `__init__.py` contains some definition like `x = 2`, then with `pkg_folder` as the current working directory or with the package installed to your Python environment, you can import `x` using

```
from pkg_name import x
```

However, if `x` is defined in a [submodule](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#submodules), things are a little different. Consider the following package structure:

```
pkg_folder
└── pkg_name
    ├── __init__.py
    └── module1.py
```

Here, `import pkg_name` again tells the interpreter to check `pkg_name/__init__.py` for name bindings. If the definition `x = 2` is in `module1.py` instead of `__init__.py`, then it is not part of `pkg_name`'s scope; instead, it belongs to `pkg_name.module1`, so the following would work:

```
from pkg_name.module1 import x
```

However, you can explicitly add it to `pkg_name` by defining a name binding for it in `__init__.py` with a [package relative import](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports). In this case, `__init__.py` might read:

```
from .module1 import x
```

Which, since `x` is now defined in `__init__.py`, allows us to reference it under `pkg_name` as well:

```
from pkg_name import x
```

The same logic applies to modules within sub-packages. So for the behavior you're looking for, you'll need to populate your sub-package's `__init__.py` files with package relative imports from the other modules within the sub-package.

To go from

```
from pkg_name.module1.module1 import func1
```

to

```
from pkg_name.module1 import func1
```

your `pkg_name/module1/__init__.py` file might resemble something like the following:

```
from .module1 import func1
```

If you had reason to, you could even extend this to propagate `func1` up to the parent package.